# Command not responding discordjs mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I have a command called inventory that uses Discord.js and MongoDB in my Discord bot. It doesn't respond and there are no errors either. Here is the code

```
const { Message } = require('discord.js')
const Client = require('../client')
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Inventory = require('./inventories')
const stats = require('./stats')

module.exports = {
    name: `inv`,
    aliases: ['inventory'],

    /**
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Message} message
     * @param {String[]} args
     */
    run: async (client, message, args) => {

        const noembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .setTitle(`${message.author.username}'s Bag`)
            .setDescription(`You have no items :(`)

        const data = await Inventory.findOne({ User: message.author.id })

        if (!data) {
            let inventory = new Inventory({
                User: message.author.id,
                Items: []
            })
            inventory.save().catch(err => console.log(err))

                .then(message.reply(noembed))
        } else if (data) {
            const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('RANDOM')
                .setTitle(`${message.author.username}'s Bag`)
                .setDescription(`${(!data.Items.length) ? "You have no items!" : `${(data.Items.join('\r\n'))}`}`)
            message.channel.send(exampleEmbed)
        }
        //            
        const data1 = await stats.findOne({ Name: 'Boblox' })
        data1.Ran += 1
        data1.save()

    },
    timeout: 2500
}
```

What is the problem with this code? I don't receive any errors when I run it. Inventory is a section in the database and I have an inventory but it doesn't send it

Comment: Are you sure it is actually running? Try putting a console.log at the top and see if it logs.

Comment: Aside from your issue, your `.then(message.reply(noembed))` is probably wrong. You probably meant to use an arrow function there, instead of calling `message.reply` directly and passing the result to `.then`.

Comment: @MrMythical the file just doesnt seem to run but every other file does

Comment: @MrMythical In that case the error is most likely not in the file itself. Check how you are loading commands - its probably folder-based. Is the command file in the correct folder to be loaded?